# Mybatis generator extend private class

Tags: mybatis

I use mybatis generator with eclipse plugin, and want that the tables create from mybatis extend a my private class (error) that have created in java, how can do? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a **`private`** class is not posible, but if this is **`public`**, you can try using the property `rootClass` in a `<property>` child element in the `<javaModelGenerator>` element, something like:

```
<javaModelGenerator targetPackage="test.model"
     targetProject="\MyProject\src">
  <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true" />
  <property name="trimStrings" value="true" />
  <property name="rootClass" value="com.mycompany.MyRootClass" />
</javaModelGenerator>
```

For more details, see the guide in [*Introduction to MyBatis Generator*](http://mybatis.org/generator/index.html).

Comment: Thanks i had not seen this property.